# how to can android studio 4.0 be used to run standard kotlin projects?

Tags: android, kotlin, configuration

In Run/Debug Configurations, in **MainClass**, it does not find the **Main** method!

**Error :** Main method is not static in class com.example.kotlinlibrary.MainClass, please define the main method as:

**Screenshots :**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make `main()` be a top-level function.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the MainClass.k Like this

```
   class Abc(){
    init{
       println("inside Man Class")
    }
  }

    fun main(){
     val obj=Abc()
    }
```

Now check on the left side of man function. A play button will be shown. Now you can run the StandAlone program.